# Meteor User Accounts - OnSignin

Tags: meteor, user-accounts

I've changed my schema to include sub-schemas. I want to group relevant data together and make it easier to manage. Unfortanly this has broken my registration process. How do I make the autoform insert firstName into the sub-schema. Any thoughts?

Path: `at_config.js`

```
AccountsTemplates.addFields([
    {        
        _id: "details.firstName",
        type: 'text',
        displayName: "First name",
        required: true,
        minLength: 1,
        maxLength: 37
    }
]);
```

Path: `Schema.js`

```
AccountsTemplates.configure({

Schema.UserDetails = new SimpleSchema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        optional: false
    }
});

Schema.UserProfile = new SimpleSchema({
    details: {
        type: Schema.UserDetails,
        optional: true
    },
});

Schema.User = new SimpleSchema({
    profile: {
        type: Schema.UserProfile,
        optional: true
    }   
});


Meteor.users.attachSchema(Schema.User);
```

Path: `startup.js`

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
    if (options.profile && options.profile.roles) {
      //include the user profile
      Roles.setRolesOnUserObj(user, options.profile.roles);
    }

    if (options.profile) {
      // include the user profile
      user.profile = options.profile;
    }

    return user;
  });
```

Comment: What is the error you're seeing?

Comment: First name: Required Field is the error.

Comment: @StephenWoods any thoughts?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is happening because you aren't setting the required field firstName on insert.  When you're setting user.profile, are you sure it includes user.profile.details.firstName?  That's what your schema says is required.

Comment: I thought it might be something like that but I'm not sure how to implement it. I've tried editing startup.js somehow but nothing I've tried works. Do you know what I'd need to do? @StephenWoods

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't used autoform before - hopefully someone else can answer.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for looking. @StephenWoods